# Problem with training a simple linear VSM classifier

Tags: r

My code:

```
library(kernlab)
 letter_classifier <- ksvm(letter ~ ., data = letters_train,
                       kernel = "vanilladot")
```

The error:

> ```
> >  Setting default kernel parameters   Error in .local(x, ...) :    No
> > Support Vectors found. You may want to change your parameters In
> > addition: Warning message: In .local(x, ...) : NAs introduced by
> > coercion
> ```

Comment: Best provide a glimpse of your data. It is possible the error lies there.

Answer (score 0):

Check the structure of `letters_train`.

SVM is for continuous and categorical variable analysis, and surely one of your variables (letter) is likely still a character variable. Change it to factor and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into same issue. The csv I used is from the link shown as below
https://github.com/stedy/Machine-Learning-with-R-datasets/raw/master/letterdata.csv
when I used letter, it showed this error message.

> letter_classifier <- ksvm(letter ~., data = letters_train, kernel = "vanilladot")
> Setting default kernel parameters
> Error in .local(x, ...) :
> No Support Vectors found. You may want to change your parameters
> In addition: Warning message:
> In .local(x, ...) : NAs introduced by coercion

However when I changed letter to as.factor(letter),it works.